# cannot find class bpelBlock error in JDeveloper

Tags: oracle11g, compiler-errors, soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I have manually made changes to the `BPEL Process`. It was a *One Way Process* but I have converted it into *Synchronous Process* by manually adding import statements, namespaces, messages & port type.

However, while compiling, `JDeveloper` is giving the following error:

```
 E:\Templates\appl\proj\SCA-INF\bpel\BPELPr~0\src\orabpel\bpelprocess\BIN0.java
 Error(54,5):  cannot find class bpelBlock
 Error(54,24): cannot find class bpelBlock
 Error(94,28): cannot find variable C0 
 Error(95,20): cannot find variable C0
```

If anyone could suggest anything, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you can delete what's in SCA-INF. I would start with doing that. You may need to first exit JDeveloper. Delete SCA-INF. Open JDeveloper recompile.

Answer (score 1):

I did RnD and figured out the solution. It was due to that I have changed it manually via Java code in which I used replace() method. It replaced the occurrence of BPEL Process name everywhere including the SCA-INF folder. When I compiled after changing the code, I gave me compilation error. This was because it changed the default BPELProcessBlock in SCA-INF\bpel\BPELPr~0\src\orabpel\bpelprocess\BIN0.java to bpelBlock. JDeveloper could not be able to find the default BPELProcessBlock and hence the error.